# Send data from one server to another and view the send data on the reciving server

Tags: php, web-services, php-curl

i want to ask if this is possible - a user is on server A, he performs certain actions and a result is generated. now instead of showing this result on server A i want it to show it on server B. 
**Example**- user does task on server A the results is generated at server A and than the result is send to Server B and the data is displayed on server B by redirecting the user to server B from server A.
Is this scenario possible?

Comment: Sure, it's possible with some work.

Comment: "the data is displayed on server B by redirecting the user to server B from server A" ...if you do that the data is not displayed on server B at all, it's just displayed the user's browser because you redirected them to server A. If that's what you're going to do you don't need to send the actual data to server B, you just need some way for server B to know that it's available. But you know an abstract scenario like this often hides the real purpose and subtleties. Without knowing what you're really trying to implement it's hard to give any more than very vague advice.

Comment: thank you guys for the quick reply.
@Jon Stirling can you explain how is the scenario possible.

Comment: No. There are too many possibilities, along with too many unknowns making this question far too broad for SO. Try yourself first, then if you have specific programming questions about issues with your own solution, feel free to drop back in.

Comment: @ADyson ok here is what i am trying to achieve. User clicks on an activation link received in his email. the links hits server A and validation is done, if validation was successfull an image is genearted, that image is than converted to base_64 string and this base_64 string is send to server B where the user can view this image or download it. i have completed the task of generating base_64 string. now want to send this string to server B or displayed it on server B. how can i achieve that?

Comment: @JonStirling can you check my comment above. that is what i want to achieve. i tried but was not able to do that task. any help

Comment: But why do you need to send it to server B? Why not just display it to the user immediately for viewing/download? It's not clear what the purpose is of this data transfer between servers.

Comment: @ADyson it is task i want to achieve. will be helpful in completing my project. Please i know this is possible but i am not able to do so. need your help.

Comment: That's not a reason. It would be far simpler and easier just to display it to the user directly on server A. If you need to save a record of it to server B for some reason then you could do that as a separate task. There is more than one way to skin a cat...we'd like to find the best way of handling this particular cat. There's no point suggesting a solution that's more complicated than it actually needs to be. So again, why exactly does the data need to go to server B first? Why not just give it to the user directly?

Comment: consider server A has an Algorithm using this Algorithm the image is generated and for keeping this Algorithm safe i have implemented it on a different server i.e server A.

Comment: "for keeping this algorithm safe" ...so server B is not secure?? Anyway that still doesn't explain why server A can't directly respond to the request and display the data to the user for download. Why do you want to send it to server B before displaying?? Since you can't explain I'm starting to think you don't actually have a practical reason for wanting to do so?

Comment: @ADyson as i told you server A will be containing algorithm. server A and sever B will be used by same organization. the employees will work on server B and not on server A. they will not have access to server A, only few will have access to server A and the users will be interacting with user B. i have made an api call to send data from server B to A. the company employees should not peak into algorithm thats why it is being implemented on server A. i hope you understand what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Ok that really wasn't clear because earlier you said "the links [from the activation email] hits server A", implying that the user _does_ have direct access to server A.

Comment: So anyway if the activation link takes the user to server B, then server B can send an API request to server A to get the image. All you need to do then is receive the data contained in the response from server A (it will contain the image data I assume) and then display it to the user. What exactly is the difficulty there? Does A not return the image data immediately in the response, perhaps?

Comment: P.S. " the company employees should not peak into algorithm thats why it is being implemented on server A". If server B and A are web application servers then the user only has access to what the webserver allows them to do via HTTP. All they see is the HTML that's returned to their browser. If you've got a standard webserver type of setup then the users cannot see any actual code which is running on server B. If all you're concerned about is security then there should be no reason to host the algorithm on a different server (there could be other good reasons, but that's not one of them).

Comment: @ADyson to understand the whole scenario i think we should have a personal chat. is that possible?

Comment: In theory yes but unfortunately you will need at least 20 reputation on this site before it will allow you to join a chat

Comment: any other way to chat @ADyson?

Comment: If there was I would have mentioned it already :). Of course we can continue to write in these comments but it's not ideal. You can address my specific comments at least

Comment: I still did not got answer to my question. And I don't think contacting you on social media will be good idea. @ADyson

Comment: Which question? About other ways to chat, I answered that. Regarding the actual question you posted above, I'm not giving a direct answer to that because it smells of an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - that's why I'm asking you further questions about the real scenario, and questioning why you have built the system the way you have. It sounds like you can probably remove server A entirely if you have got server B set up properly. But since you didn't respond to my comments about that (i.e. to validate my assumptions or not) then we can't go any further with the discussion.

Comment: i will explain you the whole scenario. but this comment section is getting too long. can we have a talk on some other platform. because this is haunting me for 2 days now. can't get it right. need real help.

Comment: if you can find somewhere easy where a free chat can be conducted then feel free to link me to it. I'm not giving out my personal social media or other communication details however, since everything typed in these pages is freely google-able.

Comment: I'm not going to mail you, sorry, because then you'll know my mail address, and I don't give it out to random strangers on forums. Nothing personal you understand. You might want to remove your comment above before the spam bots find it. If you're still desperate for help then like I said see if you can find a site that offers free chat rooms or something. Then link me to the room. Or try and get 20 reputation here (it's not that hard - a handful of upvotes) so you can use this site's chat feature.

Comment: hi... @ADyson. sorry for the late reply. i have found an Android app named HelloTalk. can you please install that app and check it out. you personal info will not be exposed their. i have already made an account on that app. please reply when you have an account their

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Here is a very simple example:

script on server A:

```
<?php

// do some calculation based on the input
$result = $_GET['number1'] + $_GET['number2'];

//redirect to Server B, pass the result as a parameter in the URL
header("Location: //server-b.org/displayResult?result=$result");
exit;
```

script on server B:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['result'];
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but the thing is that i don't want to pass the data in URL and also the the data i want to send is big so i don't think passing through URL will work. Any other solution will be helpful.

Comment: Then you need to send a POST request to server B.

Instead of header(Location: ...) you would use cURL (you need to look up how to use it). With cURL you can call a URL on any server and also send large Postdata. Server B needs to store the data it receives in a file or in a database.

Then, after the cURL call is done, you can redirect (again with header(Location: ...)) to a URL on server B, that loads the data it just saved.

Comment: can you please ellaborate

Comment: i tried that. but i want to display the data, not to store it. Thanks for the solution. any other solution

Comment: see here is the scenario- server A generates an image using php GD and than i convert it to base_64 string. now i want this string to send to server B where the user can see this image. i hope you understood the scenario. 
Please any help will appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply display the file from server A on server B? (as in, send the image URL and then use that in the img tag on server B)

Comment: how can i send the image URL from A to B. remember it should also redirect from A to B so that the user can see it

Comment: My original answer would work just fine for this. If it should not be a GET request but you want a 'simple' redirect, you could do this:

Have a HTML form on server A with action='//serverB/someURL' and method='POST' and an input field that holds the image URL. Then use javascript to send the form instantly. This will redirect you to the action URL of the form, and the input is sent as well, of course.

Comment: i can try that. thanks. but any other solution without the need for an extra page.